# Integer multiplication in 5T(n/3)

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

x and y has n bits

```
x=x0*(10^2n/3)+x1*10^n/3+x2 y=y0*(10^2n/3)+y1*10^n/3+y2

x*y=x2y2+(x2y1+x1y2)10^n/3+(x2y0+x1y1+x0y2)10^2n/3+(x1y0+x0y1)10^n+x0y0*10^4n/3
```

now 9 multiplication of n/3 bit numbers running time 9T(n/3) which is O(n^2)

with little trick like Karatsuba's multiplication

first calculate x0y0, x1y1 and x2y2 this is 3 multiplication of n/3 bit numbers

then use x0y0, x1y1 and x2y2 to calculate the others follow: x2y1+x1y2=(x1+x2)(y1+y2)-x1y1-x2y2 ->> 1 multiplication of n/3 bit number x2y1+x1y1+x0y2=(x0+x2)(y0+y2)-x0y0-x2y2+x1y1 ->> 1 multiplication of n/3 bit number x1y0+x0y1=(x0+x1)(y0+y1)-x0y0-x1y1 1 multiplication of n/3 bit number
Recursively solve the 6 subproblems and combine them with
7 additions on O(n)-digit numbers.
total it takes now 6 multiplication of of n/3 bit numbers running time 6T(n/3)

how can I reduce this to 5 multiplication instead of 6 ?

Comment: By `T`, do you mean Theta?

Comment: recursively T(n)=6T(n/3)+cn

Comment: That's a recursive definition for `T`.  How is `T` related to the problem of multiplying two `n` bit numbers?  Is `T` the number of operations required to multiply two `n` bit numbers?  (In which case, `T(n)=9T(n/3)` would show that `T(n)` is `O(n^2)` in your initial case.)  You're jumping into the middle of the problem, without telling us what you're doing.

Comment: And why did you ask this question when http://stackoverflow.com/q/26209076/2336725 is still going?  I'm going to ignore this question now, and may decide to focus on the original one (or maybe not).

Comment: @sel I edit your original question with this new stuff You should  delete this question to avoid confusion.

Comment: This question confuses me less than the first attempt, even the 6th revision thereof. `T` is probably for time, as opposed to `S` for space; and in contrast to big/small o/omega/theta, factors _do_ matter. Good bye Анато́лий Алексе́евич Карацу́ба(Anatoly Alexeevitch Karatsuba), hello, [Andrei Toom and Stephen Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication#Details).